# Чем отличаются присваивания GNU make?

Tags: makefile, gnu

В документе [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) указано несколько вариантов присваивания переменных, в частности:

1. immediate = deferred
2. immediate := immediate

В чем разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для формы

```
immediate = deferred
```

значение переменной определяется в момент использования.

```
VAR_X := 1
VAR_Y = $(VAR_X)
VAR_X := 2
# VAR_Y равно 2
```

Для формы

```
immediate := immediate
```

значение переменной определяется в момент присваивания.

```
VAR_X := 1
VAR_Y := $(VAR_X)
VAR_X := 2
# VAR_Y равно 1
```